# Any cobordism invariant made of "characteristic classes", on unorientable manifolds, must be a mod 2 class?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, cobordism

For any cobordism invariant (or simply bordism invariant) quantity $\omega$ that satisfy the conditions:

- $\omega$ can be fully decomposed from the cup product of **characteristic classes** (such as Stiefel Whitney class, Chern class, etc.).
- $\omega$ can be defined on an *unorientable smooth* manifold.

then question:

> Could we show that this $\omega$  has to be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} : = \mathbb{Z}_2$ valued (a mod 2 class)? Is this true or false?

From the recent post: [Cobordism invariants: topological v.s. geometric](https://mathoverflow.net/q/355684/27004), I recall that:

(1). The 2d $Pin^-$ bordism invariant  (defined on unorientable manifolds)  from $\Omega_2^{Pin^-}=\mathbb{Z}_8$, where any 2-manifold $M$ always admits a $Pin^-$ structure. The $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is a Arf-Brown-Kervaire (ABK) invariant. $Pin^-$ structures are in one-to-one correspondence with quadratic enhancements
$q: H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)\to\mathbb{Z}_4$ such that $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_2$, we have 
$q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y)=2\int_M x\cup y\mod4.$ In particular,
$q(x)=\int_M x\cup x\mod2.$ The $x,y$ counts as a *cohomology class*, but the ABK invariant seems not be decomposed from decomposed from a cup product of  **characteristic classes** only? *But does this count as a counter example of the above statement?*

(2) The 4d $\Omega_4^{Pin^+}(B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_{16}$ contains an [$\eta$ invariant](https://mathoverflow.net/q/163482/27004) of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, and a quadratic refinement of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (from $B \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $H^4(M,\mathbb{Z}_4)$. (It is probably similar to Pontryagin square $P(B)$ of $B \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$; but Pontryagin square $P(B)$ is defined on an orientable $SO$ structure, here I am looking at the unorientable $Pin^+$ structure.  *But does this count as a counter-example of the above statement?*

If the above statement is false, can one give counter examples?

Many thanks for comments/answers.